# AspectJ Opening multiple threads

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to use AspectJ for  authorization and for request response logging. But the issue is it's opening two threads. Executing my controller and service method twice. Any help would be appriciated.

```
@Around("execution(* com.a.b.c.controller.*.*(..)) && @annotation(com.a.b.c.role.auth.ReadAuthorization) && args(request,obj)")
public Object before(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,HttpServletRequest request,Object obj)      throws Throwable {
    Object result = null;
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("You are not authorized");
    }
    
    LoggingObject loggingObject = new LoggingObject();
    loggingObject.setMethodName(MethodSignature.class.cast(joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getName());
    loggingObject.setRequestObject(obj);
    try{
        Object requestObject = joinPoint.proceed();
        loggingObject.setResponseObject(requestObject);
        log.info(mapperObj.writeValueAsString(loggingObject));
    }catch(Exception e){
        loggingObject.setResponseObject(e);
        log.info(mapperObj.writeValueAsString(loggingObject));
    }

    if (auth.authorize(request.getHeader("id"),request.getHeader("token"))) {
        result = joinPoint.proceed();
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("You are not authorized");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: (1) AspectJ never creates threads, unless you do that yourself manually inside the aspect. (2) Your code is just a snippet, not a complete aspect class. It also does not contain the target classes you want to intercept. Hence nobody can see what is going on or reproduce your problem. Please consider to provide a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I am risking an educated guess, even though the question is unclear with you talking about threads (see my questions in the comment about how you can improve the question):

What you probably mean is simply that the target method is executed twice, not that the aspect creates two threads, correct? Well, your **advice method contains two `proceed()` calls.** Why would you be surprised if the target method is executed twice if you call it twice by yourself?

I think that should answer your question.